# Invalid cast from List<MyType> to IEnumerable<MyType> back to List<MyType>, why?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

So basically i have this method.

```
public List<Customer> FilterCustomersByStatus(List<Customer> source, string status)
{
    return (List<Customer>)source.Where(c => c.Status == status);
}
```

I throws me an error that it cannot cast:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[AppDataAcces.Customer]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AppDataAcces.Customer]'.

Why...? since the underlying type is the same, does the Enumerable.Where create a new instance of WhereListIterator and if so why would anyone do this, because thats an unnecessary loss of performance and functionality since i always have to create a new list (.ToList())

Comment: With Linq, it creates an enumerable/enumerator and dynamically iterates through your collection without creating a new one.  It doesn't actually return a `List` object unless you make a call to `.ToList()`.  The reason it does this is for performance and limit memory usage; given a list of 1000000 entries, Linq can filter/select through all the items without having to copy the list every time.

Comment: Would you please explaing why do you need `List` every time? Especially if it contains 500k entries, as you say.

Comment: I like to keep them in a List so that i may add/modify some of its elements and even if i keep them in an IEnumerable upon displaying the items i still need something to enumerate my objects in order to get them, altough im looking for the implementation relevance of this method not my work relevance.

Comment: What's the point of adding or modifying items to *filtered* list? Can you show us somewhat bigger part of your code, and describe the scenario you're trying to solve?

Comment: Im am not trying to solve any special scenario, just trying to understand why its implemented this way(what is the benefit)?. That's why i asked here, nothing more.

Comment: I've update my answer with explanation *why*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> does the Enumerable.Where create a new instance of `WhereListIterator`

Yes.

> and if so why would anyone do this

Because it allows lazy streaming behavior. `Where` won't have to filter all the list if its consumer wants only first or second entry. This is normal for LINQ.

> because thats an unnecessary loss of performance and functionality since i always have to create a new list (.ToList())

That "loss of performance and functionality" comes from your design. You don't need `List<Customer>` after filtering, because it's pointless to do any modifications on it.

**Update: "why is it implemented so"**
Because it it implemented over `IEnumerable`, not `IList`. And thus it looks like `IEnumerable`, it quacks like `IEnumerable`.

Besides, it's just so much easier to implement it this way. Imagine for a moment that you have to write `Where` over `IList`. Which has to return `IList`. What should it do? Return a proxy over original list? You'll suffer huge performance penalties on every access. Return new list with filtered items? It'll be the same as doing `Where().ToList()`. Return original list but with all non-matching items deleted? That's what `RemoveAll` is for, why make another method.

And remember, LINQ tries to play functional, and tries to treat objects as immutables.

Comment: thanks Serg your answer is pretty explicit. But if it dumps the List after filtering, and transforms it into IEnumerable (that just holds the references to my items, not the physical items) wich i will again make a List (new one using .ToList) my gain is where? Please bare with me.

Comment: It doesn't dump anything. It holds internal reference to original `IEnumerable` and builds another iterator over it. And another on next call. And so on. You gain is in the fact that you won't process all the items until you need them - and you almost never do.

Comment: if you have knowledge of a good article on how it works, i would highly appreciate it.

Comment: [Skeet's "C# in Depth"](http://manning.com/skeet2/) has good section on iterators.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, you need to use `ToList` to convert the result to `List<T>`.

The reason is that `Where` is lazily evaluated, so `Where` does not *really* filter the data.
What it does is create an `IEnumerable` which filters data as needed.

Lazy evaluation has several benefits. It might be faster, it allows using `Where` with infinite `IEnumerable`s, etc.

`ToList` forces the result to be converted to `List<T>`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Well, the fact that `Where()` is lazy is not really relevant here. The fact that is doesn't return `List<T>` is.

Comment: I want a list , and i know that ToList accomplishes that, i just want to know why does it not keep the underlying type so i need to create a new list each time?

Comment: @svick Point is `Where` is not only lazy, but also streaming, and you can't return `List` and still be streaming.

Comment: @svick I don't think `List<T>` can ever be lazy. At most, it *could* return `IList<T>` if Linq was IList-only, which it isn't. As for why, I guess that - for long chains of LINQ functions - lazy evaluation is just usually more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The Where extension filters and returns `IEnumerable<TSource>` hence you need to call .ToList() to convert it back

```
public List<Customer> FilterCustomersByStatus(List<Customer> source, string status)
{
    return source.Where(c => c.Status == status).ToList();//This will return a list of type customer
}
```

Comment: Please may i request you to explain -1

Comment: Explain what? i just want to know why generate new lists each time as its poor in performance especially with 500 000+ entries.

Comment: @Freeman I agree performance is poor so you should change you return type to Customer[] and in the Where clause call .ToArray() instead of .ToList(). The ToArray with return declared typed byt you won't get benefits of a List

Comment: Even if i return an array upon wich i will use the same Where method, will it not return the same IEnumerable type?

Comment: @Freeman When you call .ToArray() it creates an Array of Ineumerable<out T> that will be Customer[]

Comment: So its not the same return type all the time(at least for its base type).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between IEnumerable and IList is, the enumerable doesn't contain any data, it contains an [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) that goes through the data as you request the new one (for example, with a foreach loop). On the other hand, the list is a copy of the data. In your case, to create the List, ToList() method iterates through the entire data and adds them to a List object.

Depending to the usage you are planning, both have advantages and disadvantages. For example, if you are planning to use the entire data more than once, you should go with the list, but if you are planning to use it once or you are planning to query it again using linq, enumerable should be your choice.

Edit:
The answer to the question why the return type of Where is WhereListIterator instead of List is, it's partly because how Linq works. For example, if you had another Where or another Linq statement following the first, the compiler would create a single query using the entire method chain, then return the iterator for the final query. On the other hand, if the first Where would return a List that would cause each Linq method in the chain execute separately on the data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public List<Customer> FilterCustomersByStatus(List<Customer> source, string status)
{
    return source.Where(c => c.Status == status).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The main question is “Why?” You don't even try to answer that.